# Hibernate creating Schemas on each application run?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping

I have built a web application using MVC pattern and Hibernate. I am trying to configure my hibernate to create schemas for my classes by using following property

`<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>`

But, I found out that this drops the previous existing schema and re-creates schema on each application run. Is there anyway I configure my hibernate to create schemas only on my first application run and for any future application run just update the rows in existing database?

Comment: try `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>`

Comment: the syntax is working fine.But, every time I stop and re-run my application it deleting old values and creating tables all over again. Is there way where I can instruct hibernate to create tables only if they are not present else just update rows in it

Comment: `create` is to create schema destroying previous data. You can use `update` to make changes, only if, they are not present. Other two options are `create-drop` and `none`. But not sure if it is what you are asking for.

Comment: But if I make it as `update` it is not creating any schemas on the first run of my application

Comment: four possible values are `create`, `update`, `create-drop`, and `validate`. It is not recommended to use create, update or create-drop in production environment.  In your local, if you do not have a schema you should use `create` first and `update` thereafter.

Comment: is there a way I can automate(`Create` schemas if not present else `Update` ) rather than having to touch the code again?

Comment: Not exactly what you are looking for but as an alternative - If `Update` is not working as is replied by @Ajay Kumar below, there are other options like `flyway` or `liquibase`.  These tools are used for db versioning, maybe that will help in your case.

Answer (score 0):

As YomanTaMero mentioned instead of :

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

try this:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

> **Noticed "update" above?**

Comment: But if I make it as `update` it is not creating any schemas on the first run of my application

Comment: @aelina `update` will create a schema(s) if it do not exists, otherwise it'll update the existing schema(s).